# how to install premium theme to Magento 2.0 localhost

Tags: magento2, theme

Recently i have brought a **Magento Theme** and trying to install it to my **localhost**. I am using **Magento 2.0** in wamp in Windows. To install it, i have followed the instruction [here](http://newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/video_guide/)

I just extract and copy-paste them directly to my project as instructed in the video. At the ***"Theme Installation"*** video of that link, i am somewhat lost because of the changed interface of **Magento-2.0**.

Even if i paste it right,on Magento 2.0 dashboard, under *content->Design->Theme*, it doesn't show any name of that theme.

So, guide me through the whole process step by step please.

Comment: Please do not use localhost as your domain name. alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.x extensions/themes are not supported at all in Magento 2.x. Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x follows a different module structure and code syntaxes are also different. You need to purchase/develop themes which is specially compatible with Magento 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

you can paste theme in app/design/frontend directory
if you want to know file structure then you can check below url.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 1):

The video posted is for Magento 1, which is not the same as in Magento 2. You will need a Magento2 specific theme, which has a `registration.php`

Comment: I think my theme is for Magento 1.9.2.2 because it has a patch for Magento 1.9.2.2. Will i be able to use it on Magento 2.0?@Maddy

Comment: No. Magento 1 Themes are not compatible with Magento 2